# Boarding a flight without a visa intending to claim asylum

Tags: visas, tickets, canada, airlines, refugees

I don't have a Canadian visa. I believe I can get and qualify for refugee status... The problem is getting to Canada.

Is it possible for me to board a flight to Canada and once I arrive at immigration claim that I want to apply for refugee status?

Would an airline allow me to board a flight to Canada with me saying I plan to apply for refugee status once in Canada?

Would an airline allow me to board if I have hard evidence that my life is in danger of a genocide attack due to race and heritage.

I can't apply from outside Canada for refugee status: the 18-month+ waiting period can result in serious consequences.

Can anyone provide me with advice?

Many thanks.

PS I won't be / don't plan to be a burden on society. I'm not looking for free handouts or medical or any benefits. I'm qualified, skilled, and am more than willing to make my own path in Canada without assistance. I'm only looking for a safe haven.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65184/discussion-on-question-by-gekkogurru-boarding-a-flight-without-a-visa-intending).

Comment: This question is not about immigrating (long or short term) but about being allowed on a flight. (I am afraid the answer is 'you will not be allowed on the flight.'

Comment: If you plan to claim asylum in Canada,and you are comming from US,your only choice is to enter into the country by land,illegally. Because of the [Canada-U.S. Safe Third Country Agreement](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/laws-policy/menu-safethird.asp), if you enter by an official point of entry and you claim asylum, comming from US, you will be immediately sent back to US because it is considered by Canada as a "safe country" where you can also claim asylum. However if you enter illegally, the accord is not applied. There is a lot of controversy around this accord currently in Canada

Comment: You should also inform yourself about how the asylum process works in Canada, you risk a lot by doing this without doing some research first: http://globalnews.ca/news/3696080/misinformation-illegal-crossing-canada-wrong-information-campaign/

Comment: @Willeke By that argument, questions about work permits are on-topic here, too. After all, they're "questions about getting visas", not "about immigrating".

Answer (score 4):

**No airline will allow you to get on a flight to Canada without a visa or other evidence that you will be admitted.** They will not take your word that you qualify, or even intend to apply for, refugee status, and they have neither the time nor ability to evaluate your claim of persecution.

Your only option is to obtain a visa that will allow you entry to Canada, use it to legally travel there, and then make a refugee claim. If you can get to the US legally you can make a claim there or get to Canada.

Questions about making a refugee claim would be better on our [Expatriates site](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com).